# How can I access a class field by its name in racket?

Tags: oop, racket

I can access a class field by defining a method so `(send joe get-name)` will return me `Joe`. But can I get the same behavior without adding a method and just by calling a field, like this: `(send joe name)`?

```
#lang racket

(define person%
  (class object%
    (init-field name)
    (super-new)
    (define/public (get-name) name) ))

(define joe (new person% [name 'Joe]))
```

Comment: I know I'm not answering your question at all, but: are you sure you need classes, here? Structs are a lot simpler and this question has a simple answer in that domain.

Comment: Yes, I need to know if it is possible with classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`get-field`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/ivaraccess.html?q=get-field#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fclass-internal..rkt%29._get-field%29%29).

Example of usage: `(get-field name joe)`

Let me know if I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of using it?

Comment: have you tried it, or read the documentation? Stack overflow is a "proof-of-work" site, where you show what you've tried, and *then* we do more work for you :).

Comment: Wouldn't ask you if I didn't. Probably I didn't use it correctly the first time, so it didn't work for me. Now it works, gonna add it to your answer.